# jsoup : Absolute path while working with files

Tags: java, jsoup, relative-path, absolute-path

I got some page repository with html files. I want to process them using jsoup, but when I try to get absolute paths of all links jsoup gave me empty strings (`""`). Is there a possibility to set baseUri as a file path ?

Solution : `link.get(i).baseUri + link.get(i).attr("href")` is not sufficient for me becouse i need to some how recognize which link is relative or not.

The jsoup documentation says us :

> There is a sister method parse(File in, String charsetName) which uses
>   the file's location as the baseUri. This is useful if you are working
>   on a filesystem-local site and the relative links it points to are
>   also on the filesystem.

But it doesn't work on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm "solving" the same issue with the following code. While I prefer jsoup functions worked on my local file system, I need something in the meantime. That solution is sending the file locations into the parser as the baseURI then concatenating each relative path to that base. Unfortunately, that means I lose the nesting functionality of HTML's "../" that jsoup normally handles with its built-in functions. Furthermore, I can never be as certain about the results as if the built-in functions worked.

Luckily, I use this mainly for JUnit Testing and it should add minor risks to my production code. The context is that I built a local "Internet" to test crawling offline. I create the JSoup Document by sending a local HTML file to it in my JUnit Test Class:

```
// From my JUnit Test
String testFileName = "HTMLTest_RelativeReferences.html";
String testFilePath = getClass().getResource(testFileName).getPath();
String testFileBaseURI = testFilePath.replace(testFileName, "");

// ...
// Sends filePath and baseURI to testing class that creates JSoup Doc with:
siteDoc = Jsoup.parse(new File(testFilePath), "UTF-8", testFileBaseURI);
```

Now that I created my Document with a baseURI, you & I both thought the relative paths should use that baseURI to create an absolute path. Since that failed, I run a simple test for empty-string abs:refs and concatenate my own URLs.

```
Elements links = siteDoc.select("a[href]"); // extract link collection
for (Element link : links) { // iterate through links
    String linkString = link.attr("abs:href"); // ftr, neither this nor absUrl("href") works
    if (linkString.isEmpty()) { // check if returned "" (i.e., the problem at hand)
        URLs.add(siteDoc.baseUri() + link.attr("href")); // concatenate baseURI to relative ref
    }
    else { // for all the properly returned absolute refs
        URLs.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
    }
}
```

All my JUnit Tests continue to pass with both absolute and relative local references - good luck!

HTML Doc I used for reference with all 3 links representing other HTML files in the same folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Test using Relative References</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="LinkedHTMLFile1.html">Link1</a>
 <a href="LinkedHTMLFile2.html">Link2</a>
 <a href="LinkedHTMLFile3.html">Link3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I little digging into the jsoup library leads me to believe our local file "URL"s will never work because jsoup handles actual URLs during its attr("abs:href") process and will through MalformedURLs and return "" since we are actually using local file paths rather than true URLs. I consider this outside of the scope of the above answer but thought I would mention my discovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absUrl()-function in JSoup Elements.

```
String path = linkEl.absUrl("href");
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it before (this is the same as link.get(i).attr("abs:href"), only empty string), but it didn't work.